# Is girl's night legal?

Tags: criminal-law

Most night club in my place have girls' night. Basically men pay to come. Girls come for free.

Obviously that is sexual discrimination.

In US, is this legal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No form of discrimination is a crime, but some forms might be a cause for a lawsuit. At the federal level, discriminating against customers in a place of public accomodation is legal if it is on the basis of sex, but not race or religion. Your state of city may have additional restrictions, for example [in Seattle](https://library.municode.com/wa/seattle/codes/municipal_code?nodeId=TIT14HURI_CH14.06UNPUACPR), sex discrimination in public accomodations is illegal; also, discrimination on the basis of political ideology is illegal, unlike any of the federal analogs.

Comment: It's illegal to discriminate based on political ideology? So I must hire nazis and racists?

Comment: That is a conspicuous First Amendment problem. Dunno why that hasn't ended up in court, or perhaps it has and it's working its way up the chain.